# Adaptive card fails to render when invoking an action command from the compose message area

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a messaging extension bot in my Teams app, which is sending the following response when it receives a `composeExtension/submitAction` POST request:

```
{
  "composeExtension": {
    "attachments": [
      {
        "content": {
          "type": "AdaptiveCard",
          "body": [
            {
              "items": [
                {
                  "color": null,
                  "horizontalAlignment": null,
                  "isSubtle": false,
                  "maxLines": 0,
                  "size": "large",
                  "text": "Solution: DoorDash",
                  "weight": "bolder",
                  "wrap": false,
                  "separator": false,
                  "type": "TextBlock"
                },
                {
                  "color": null,
                  "horizontalAlignment": null,
                  "isSubtle": true,
                  "maxLines": 0,
                  "size": "small",
                  "text": "No Needs • No Comments • No Upvotes",
                  "weight": null,
                  "wrap": true,
                  "separator": false,
                  "type": "TextBlock"
                }
              ],
              "separator": false,
              "type": "Container"
            },
            {
              "items": [
                {
                  "horizontalAlignment": null,
                  "style": null,
                  "url": "https://urlp.asm.skype.com/v1/url/content?url=https%3a%2f%2fs3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com%2fstartgrid-v2-test-crunchbase-images%2forganizations%2fb%2f2%2fb2cximlauocyxfs2lkfh",
                  "width": "100px",
                  "height": "100px",
                  "separator": false,
                  "type": "Image"
                },
                {
                  "color": null,
                  "horizontalAlignment": null,
                  "isSubtle": false,
                  "maxLines": 0,
                  "size": null,
                  "text": "",
                  "weight": null,
                  "wrap": false,
                  "separator": false,
                  "type": "TextBlock"
                },
                {
                  "color": null,
                  "horizontalAlignment": null,
                  "isSubtle": false,
                  "maxLines": 0,
                  "size": null,
                  "text": "DoorDash enables delivery in areas where it was not previously available. The company's mission is to empower small business owners to offer delivery in an affordable and convenient way. We are achieving this mission first by enabling restaurant food delivery.  DoorDash was founded in February 2013 by four Stanford students with experiences from Facebook, Square, Vevo, and eBay.",
                  "weight": null,
                  "wrap": false,
                  "separator": false,
                  "type": "TextBlock"
                }
              ],
              "separator": false,
              "type": "Container"
            }
          ],
          "actions": [
            {
              "url": "xxxxxxxxxx",
              "title": "View Solution",
              "type": "Action.OpenUrl"
            },
            {
              "url": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/task/60864eb3-18fc-4710-9029-412157bce86b?height=600&url=xxxxxxxxxxx",
              "title": "Add Comment",
              "type": "Action.OpenUrl"
            }
          ],
          "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
          "version": "1.0"
        },
        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive"
      }
    ],
    "type": "result",
    "attachmentLayout": "list"
  },
  "responseType": "composeExtension"
}
```

The POST request has a 200 status code but the adaptive card fails to render and the following error message is displayed in the console: `BotCardService: Error while resolving MRI from appAttribution. Error msg: {}`

Please could you provide further information on what this error relates to?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your requirement and share the repro steps, so that we can try it from our end and could you please share manifest json if possible.

Comment: Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved or still looking for any help?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT this is still an issue, not resolved.

Comment: Manifest file gist (I pasted only related parts): [Manifest.json](https://gist.github.com/rfaga/bc44dcbd0475074a0946d855f34b3696)

Answer (score -1):

Here are the steps you can follow:

1. We should add the commands in compose extension section in manifest file like below:

   "composeExtensions": [
   {
   "botId": "xxxxxx-59e6-49b8-8b94-xxxxxxxxxx",
   "commands": [
   {
   "id": "createAdaptiveCard",
   "type": "action",
   "context": [ "compose" ],
   "description": "Command to run action to create a Card from Compose Box",
   "title": "Adaptive Card",
   "parameters": [
   {
   "name": "title",
   "title": "Name",
   "description": "Name of the User",
   "inputType": "text"
   },
   {
   "name": "subTitle",
   "title": "Designation",
   "description": "Designation of the User",
   "inputType": "text"
   },
   {
   "name": "text",
   "title": "Description",
   "description": "Description",
   "inputType": "textarea"
   }
   ]
   },
   {
   "id": "webView",
   "description": "Fetch the Web View",
   "title": "Web View",
   "type": "action",
   "fetchTask": true,
   "context": [ "compose" ]
   },
   {
   "id": "HTML",
   "description": "Fetch the HTML",
   "title": "HTML",
   "type": "action",
   "fetchTask": true,
   "context": [ "compose" ]
   },
   {
   "id": "razorView",
   "description": "Fetch the Razor View",
   "title": "Razor View",
   "type": "action",
   "fetchTask": true,
   "context": [ "compose" ]
   }
   ]
   }
   ],
2. You need to invoke the "createAdaptiveCard" action from the Messaging Extension action.
   It will open a AdaptiveCard popup which is configured in your manifest.
   Once you submit the card, it will handle the request at server side in below method:

   **protected override async Task OnTeamsMessagingExtensionSubmitActionAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, MessagingExtensionAction action, CancellationToken cancellationToken)**
3. As a return response, you can return the Adaptive Card as attachment.
   We have tried it at our end and it is working fine.
   Please find below screenshot of it.
   [image]
   [image]

Please find below sample link for your reference:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/51.teams-messaging-extensions-action

Comment: @Laura,@robertof - Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT,@ChetanSharma-msft - this is not fixed yet, the issue seems to be with Adaptive Cards only and preview.
This is the response that our bot is generating:
https://gist.github.com/rfaga/c8768f42a78ee0f9aa9c6f03707240ff
Not sure if Laura's question was clear enough, but the issue is with PREVIEW, not the rendering itself, which is working fine.
For this GIST response, if I try to change to use a HeroCard it previews correctly, but when it is an adaptiveCard we don't see anything in the preview (but pressing return renders then the adaptiveCard correctly)

Comment: I even tried the 51. example and I see same issue, empty preview (flashes very quickly the message inside compose /input text box). Not sure if we require some extra parameter or config but it seems adaptiveCards rendering in preview is raising this `BotCardService: Error while resolving MRI from appAttribution. Error msg: {}` error

Comment: @robertof - I tried out with 51.example. it's working fine from our end. added screenshot with above answer for preview. Can you check it once is any steps is missing? or share the repro steps, so that we can try it from our end.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT preview doesn't show only for previewing adaptive cards in Teams tab. Chat for some reason works fine.
The 51.example works as it is, but if I switch to return a Adaptive Card instead HeroCard as it returns for result, the Team tab also doesn't show preview, only Chat tab.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT I did a screencast showing both places with same action and no Preview in Teams - it seems I can always see this `BotCardService: Error while resolving MRI from appAttribution. Error msg: {}` error for any adaptive card in Teams tab:
https://youtu.be/_eelXVFapJ8

Comment: @robertof - We are able to repro that issue , We have raised bug for the same and concerned team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any update.

Comment: @robertof - Bug is fixed. Could you please check it once and let me know.
Microsoft Teams Version 1.5.00.15719 (64-bit)-